# What's better [read, check, write] each or just [write] everything?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have some records in my database and new records are incoming through XML in bundles. I need to update some portion of data or create a new one if corresponding record not found. So I want to find the best way to update them in terms of performance and load on database.

**First way**: read every record one by one from XML, compare them with existing one and update only fields, that are different.

**Second way**: just update all fields for every record.

If there is another way, feel free to suggest :)

Comment: If you have unique field that is coming through the xml data, you could try to find record if not found create new, and on the record update all other attributes that come in.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you run a direct `update`, rails will make a `read/check/update` because of validations and other stuff.
Because inserts has to be done once a time, if you really want to improve you DB load, you can at least load all records once.

```
records = Model.where(id: list_of_ids)
xml_list.each do |xml_model|
  record = records.select {|r| r.id == xml_model.id}
  #do_stuff unless record.nil?
end
```

Where `list_of_ids` is an array of id.
This way, you're moving repeated searches in memory instead of the DB.
If ids are too much, take a look at [find_each](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-each)

```
records = Model.find_each
```

But you should be able to search on your xml_list by id, and I'm not sure about this...

Comment: So I don't need to check manually? For now, I'm parsing XML, then search for corresponding record with `find_by`, then update it and relative data from another tables.

Comment: Don't know what's the size of your "bundles", but what about parsing all your objects converting them into `model` objects and then loading corresponding records with my code?

Comment: Well, I 'll try to load everything with single query with `joins` and `where`.

Comment: Yeah, this is the only thing you can do to optimize. As a "short answer" to your question I would say: both first and second ways you said act the same in rails, so the only way remaining is to load (aka `read`) all you need once and then work in memory to be faster (`check/write`)

Comment: It may be a little bit offtop, but how to track deleted data? For example in my XML I receive some new data on product, but it doesn't contain list of deleted values. So what's the best way to delete them from database too?

Comment: Yeah, maybe this would deserve a new question (with some data example from your XML). Anyway, I can give you a clue. Rails is REST oriented, so usually when a field is missing it means "leave it as it is". If you need to specify a field to delete you have 2 choices (unfortunately both manual): 1) You always send the entire model (with ALL fields) through XML, so property to delete will be null or any other default value. 2) You pass a `to_delete` array with the list of properties to delete for each object an manage it inside the loop I showed you (in the `do_stuff` block)